# JPype ImportError: Class `MyClass` was found but was not expected (!?)

Tags: java, python, jpype

Today I ran into what I initially thought to be yet another "failed to import" error in JPype but then, after looking into the error message in more depth I immediately started getting a little more worried than usual:

[image: JPype error message]

The error message seems to indicate that the class actually exists in the classpath and is properly recognized (and yes I have already checked that the Java class was there and working well,  indeed) but, for some reason, the class should not be there: it was not expected!?

This is weird but even weirder is the fact that a Google search bought no results at all! Still at the time of writing there is no single mention of this kind of problem in the net, as far as I can see.

What I have done is to explore JPype's imports.py source code; the relevant snippet is shown in the image below:

[image: JPype's snippet from imports.py]

It actually seems to indicate that the class is not found with the default strategy employed by JPype but then it tries the standard Class.forName strategy of the JVM and finds it! This is possibly even more confusing than the original error message for me.

I believe I will resign myself to run a "naive" trial-and-error testing procedure, that is removing all the code that I can from the offending Java class until the problem disappears (starting from an empty file, if needed!) and then adding more and more code until the problem arises again. Unfortunately the Java file is a very complex class with 2K+ lines of code, so this is almost certainly gonna take a lot of time.

Hence my request for help to the community: does anyone has previous experience of this strange error from JPype? Any idea of where could I look for to simplify and speed up my research process?

Needless to say, if I find the solution before I get any answer I will share it below, of course!

Answer (score 1):

After completing my "naive" trial-and-error testing procedure I did found the solution to my problem myself; as promised I will share what I found here for anyone who runs into the same problem.

Basically the root of the problem was a class in the Java package that we "forgot" to add the "public" keyword to (!) As a consequence, the visibility of that class was "default", which means access to that class was set to package-private. With insight that explains quite well that strange error message: *Class was found but not expected*. Yup, that translates to: "the class is actually there but it is not public so I am sorry you can't use it".

Maybe a slightly more clear error message would have saved me a few hours of testing but that's it. Changing the declaration of the offending class in the Java package from:

```
class lljavaPDFTextStripper { ... }
```

to

```
public class lljavaPDFTextStripper { ... }
```

fixed the problem.

Comment: Now am facing this similar error, can you help me out?

Comment: @KannanT you didn't provide enough info for me to give specific advice but if your problem is similar to mine then I suggest you to check the source code of the Java class you are trying to import into your Python script, but get that error on. I bet the class is not public: if this is the case then you can try to make it public and rebuild the package.

Comment: actually i wrote a separate python script to use mpxj library, if i run that my code works fine, now i tried to use the same code with django server inside a get request am facing this error      File "/Users/kannan.thulasi/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/jpype/imports.py", line 160, in find_spec
    raise ImportError("Attempt to create Java package '%s' without jvm" % name)
ImportError: Attempt to create Java package 'net' without jvm

Comment: @KannanT I am afraid this is a different issue and a different scenario from mine. In my case the Java library was a custom library we had access to the code of, while you are using a third party library. That said, from the error message I'd guess you didn't start the JVM before attempting to load the library: let's check that you have something similar to `jpype.startJVM()` around the beginning of your Python script. BTW why are you using the Java version of mpxj in your Python scripts while there is a Python version available?